# Is it necessary to wait for window load event before initialising a ReactJS app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, virtual-dom

Is there any reason to wait for a window load event before initialising a react app?

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
   ReactDOM.render(
     <h1>Reactastic!</h1>,
     document.getElementById('rootElement')
   );
}, false);
```

As long as `rootElement` is defined in html, not hidden or created dynamically by javascript, is there any possibility that it won't be available in time for React to init?

Edit: This is also assuming that the javascript is loaded in the footer.

Comment: If you locate your JavaScript after html then rooltElement should be loaded.

Comment: to be honest, never thought about it before, I just use the default React lifecycle methods... gonna try.

Comment: you should also assume that this is either the last script element or that all following scripts ( including html5 async scripts ) don't invasively change the rendered dom tree inside 'root'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the javascript is loaded at the bottom of the page, there is no reason to wait for the document to be loaded since the `rootElement` will already be available in the DOM.

Comment: Is that guaranteed 100% of the time in all browsers? Assuming that the html is set normally (and is not manipulated in any way by other scripts) and the javascript is loaded in the footer

Comment: Yes it holds true in all browsers. If the script is added to the DOM below the `rootElement`, it will be returned by the `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector` APIs.

Answer (score 1):

the ReactDom renderer will mount everything in the container element, so, the only thing react needs(*) is an existing 'root' element at render call.
Given your assumptions, this holds true hence you don't need to wait onload() in this case.

(*)of course, any script evaluated after rendering() invasively manipulating the dom inside your 'root' element can ( and probably will ) break the react logic ...